# onclick='' is not working when trying a Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, onclick

I am trying to make a Chrome extension however onclick='' is not working when used due to inline javascript below is the code I use:

```js
let createTasks = () => {
    TaskContainer.innerHTML = `<span class='TextMyTask'>My Tasks</span>`
        data.map((x,y) => {
            TaskContainer.innerHTML +=`
            <div id=task${y} class='secondtaskcontainer'>
                <span class='tasktextclass'>${y+1}${'-'}${x.text}</span></br>
                <span class='datetextclass'>${'To do on date : '}${x.thedate}</span></br>
                <span class='descriptiontextclass'>${'This task consists to : '}${x.description}</span></br>
                <span class='urgencytextclass'>${'This task is : '}${x.urgency}</span>
                <i class="Edit" id='edit' onclick='Edittask(this)'>&#x270E;</i>
                <i  class="Trash" id='trash' onclick='Removetask(this); createTasks()'>&#128465;</i>
            </div>`
        })
    clearform()  
    savedata()  
}
```

```js
function Removetask(e){ 
    Taskid = e.parentElement.id
    let removedTask =document.getElementById('Taskid')
    const lastChar = Taskid.at(-1);
    e.parentElement.remove(removedTask)
    data.splice(lastChar,1)
    savedata()
}

function Edittask(e){
        openpopup()
        let selectededitedTaskid = e.parentElement.id
        const lastChareditedtask = selectededitedTaskid.at(-1)
        InputTask.value = data[lastChareditedtask].text
        InputDate.value = data[lastChareditedtask].thedate
        Description.value = data[lastChareditedtask].description
        Urgency.value = data[lastChareditedtask].urgency
        Removetask(e)
        savedata()
}
```

I tried to remove the onclick='' and replacing it with addEventlistener using
var Edit = document.getElementById('edit') and Edit.addEventListener('click', Edittask()) but then I get the error message 'Cannot read properties of null' as element is not yet created. May somebody help me solve this problem?

Comment: Your last attempt is almost correct. 1) Move `<script src=...` tag to the bottom of html, 2) Remove `()` in Edit.addEventListener.

Comment: Thank you for your help wOxxOm. I actually removed defer but still not working changing the method as suggested below by shik shak shok worked fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
The issue you're facing with the `addEventListener` approach is that you're invoking the `Edittask` function immediately instead of assigning it as the event listener. You need to pass the function reference without the parentheses. Here's the corrected code:
```

```js
let createTasks = () => {
    TaskContainer.innerHTML = `<span class='TextMyTask'>My Tasks</span>`;
    data.map((x, y) => {
        TaskContainer.innerHTML +=`
        <div id=task${y} class='secondtaskcontainer'>
            <span class='tasktextclass'>${y+1}${'-'}${x.text}</span></br>
            <span class='datetextclass'>${'To do on date : '}${x.thedate}</span></br>
            <span class='descriptiontextclass'>${'This task consists to : '}${x.description}</span></br>
            <span class='urgencytextclass'>${'This task is : '}${x.urgency}</span>
            <i class="Edit" id='edit'>&#x270E;</i>
            <i class="Trash" id='trash'>&#128465;</i>
        </div>`;
    });

    clearform();
    savedata();

    // Add event listeners after elements are created
    const editButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('Edit');
    for (let i = 0; i < editButtons.length; i++) {
        editButtons[i].addEventListener('click', Edittask);
    }

    const trashButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('Trash');
    for (let i = 0; i < trashButtons.length; i++) {
        trashButtons[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
            Removetask(this);
            createTasks();
        });
    }
};

// Rest of your code...
```

In the updated code, after creating the elements and appending them to the DOM, we add event listeners to the edit and trash buttons using `addEventListener`. We select the buttons using `getElementsByClassName` and loop through the collection to attach the event listeners to each button individually. Note that in the case of the trash buttons, we're using an anonymous function to call both `Removetask` and `createTasks` functions when the button is clicked.

Make sure to remove the `onclick` attributes from the HTML code since we're attaching the event listeners programmatically.

Comment: Waw Thank you very much Khalil. The proposed code and explanations are very logic. I am going to try that right now!. Again thanks a lot!

Comment: @Mehdi Thank you too and let me know if I can help with anything else. But please next time call me Shik Shak Shok, as it is against my religion to call me by my name and not the name of my dead cat.

Comment: ok Shik Shak Shok thanks a lot. I actually tried and it works fine, but still face a problem with this line e.parentElement.remove(removedTask) when pressing the edit btn. Can you still help? thanks a lot ! the whole code is available with code pen https://codepen.io/JustNewInTown/pen/ZEmGazJ

Comment: @Mehdi hope this will be helpful habibi `function Removetask(e){ 
    let Taskid = e.parentElement.id
    let removedTask = document.getElementById(Taskid)
    const lastChar = Taskid.at(-1);
    removedTask.remove()
    data.splice(lastChar,1)
    savedata()
}`

Comment: By the way, great to do list, especially liked the animations, keep up the good work! @Mehdi

Comment: @Shik Shak Shok thank you again Sadiki! you are really gifted! I changed but actualy it seems that this line "let Taskid = e.parentElement.id" and below are now giving error message. Seems that as out of the eventlistener it can't get the Id and the element that fired the event. so I am trying to find a solution. Again thks a lot and greetings from Tunisia!